# Scala spray-json type match

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

I am used to using sacla spray-json to serializate and deserializate json data.
But there have one problem confuse me for a long time:
Assume the json data is:

```
{"a":"123"}
```

but sometimes it may be:

```
{"a":123} or {"a":123.0}
```

Problem is that I don't konw the data type in advance, it may be String or Int or Doule.

When using spray-json framework, I need to determine the data format in advance.
Below is my code:

```
case class Input(a:Either[String,Numeric[Either[Int,Doule]]])

object SelfJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    // format the json type into scala type.
    implicit val InputFormat = jsonFormat1(Input)
}
```

But that was wrong when compile it.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Why don't you just define the dataType to be double and convert every value that comes to double?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, Because of some external reason, I can't determine the dataType beforehand.

Comment: you don't have to know the datatype. define your case class to be of doubleType and parse the value to double else 0.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the Either type in your case class can be made to work if you simplify it a little. Use Either[Double, String]. This way Ints are automatically parsed as Doubles.

Example:

```
import spray.json._

case class DoubleTest(a: Either[Double, String])

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val doubleTestFormat = jsonFormat1(DoubleTest)
}

import MyJsonProtocol._

val json = """[{"a":"123"}, {"a":123}, {"a":123.0}]"""
val ast = JsonParser(json)
val DTs = ast.convertTo[List[DoubleTest]]
DTs.map { dt =>
  dt.a match {
    case Left(d) => { println("double found"); d }
    case Right(d) => { println("string found"); d.toDouble }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
json: String = [{"a":"123"}, {"a":123}, {"a":123.0}]
ast: spray.json.JsValue = [{"a":"123"},{"a":123},{"a":123.0}]
DTs: List[DoubleTest] = List(DoubleTest(Right(123)), DoubleTest(Left(123.0)), DoubleTest(Left(123.0)))
string found
double found
double found
res35: List[Double] = List(123.0, 123.0, 123.0)
```

Comment: Thanks a billion, that works for me, and if I code Either[String,Numeric[Either[Int,Doule]]], it seems need to do one more type match, but it looks so redundant.

Comment: You save me a lot of time